# Inserir texto usando FFMPEG, porém só em um trecho do vídeo

Tags: bash, vídeo

Utilizo o código abaixo para gerar novos vídeos (da respectiva pasta) inserindo o nome e o CPF do aluno em cada vídeo.

Porém, dessa forma, a compilação demora muito, já que o tempo de compilação é o tempo do vídeo. Eu preciso de algo mais rápido, quero que seja inserido o texto apenas do 5º ao 10º segundo do vídeo e depois pare.

Como se dividisse o vídeo, inserisse o texto. Sem precisar compilar o vídeo todo.
Acredito que seja necessário, antes, fazer uma cópia dos vídeos e depois um código que apenas insira o texto no tempo.

O script que utilizo é:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Nome do aluno"
read nome;
echo "CPF do aluno"
read cpf;

mkdir $cpf;

echo “iniciando a compilação para o aluno $nome”

[ "$1" ] && cd "$1"

ls -1 *.mp4
[ "$?" -ne 0 ] && echo 'Sem arquivos mp4 nesse diretório' && exit 0
for ARQUIVO in $(ls -1 *.mp4)
do
    ARQ_DESTINO="${ARQUIVO%%.mp4}.mp4"
    echo "Convertendo $ARQUIVO para $ARQ_DESTINO"
    ffmpeg -i "$ARQUIVO" -strict experimental -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf':text='Liberado para $nome - $cpf':x=200:y=10:fontsize=16:enable='between(t,5,10)'" /var/www/Arquivos/videos/$cpf/"$ARQ_DESTINO"
done
```

Como irei vender vídeos on-line, eu montei um server para criar esses vídeos. Porém, cada pacote de aula tem em torno de 6 horas de duração. Se 4 pessoas comprarem por dia meu servidor irá trabalhar o dia todo para montar esses novos vídeos. Assim fica inviável, existe uma solução mais rápida?

Comment: Não posso testar, mas acredito que a solução é *split and concat*: [Join mp4 files in linux](http://superuser.com/q/521113/138315). Um arquivo com os 5 primeiros segundos, outro com os 5 segundos personalizados criados on-the-fly e outro com o restante.

Answer (score -1):

Veja se essa solução te atende. Eu criei alguns arquivos temporários para colocar o texto em apenas uma parte.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Nome do aluno"
read nome;
echo "CPF do aluno"
read cpf;

mkdir $cpf;

echo “iniciando a compilação para o aluno $nome”

[ "$1" ] && cd "$1"

ls -1 *.mp4
[ "$?" -ne 0 ] && echo 'Sem arquivos mp4 nesse diretório' && exit 0
for ARQUIVO in $(ls -1 *.mp4)
do
    ARQ_DESTINO="${ARQUIVO%%.mp4}.mp4"
    echo "Convertendo $ARQUIVO para $ARQ_DESTINO"

    # Arquivo s temporários do início meio e fim do vídeo
    ffmpeg -i "$ARQUIVO" -c copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:05 -avoid_negative_ts 1  inicio.mp4
    ffmpeg -i "$ARQUIVO" -c copy -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 -avoid_negative_ts 1  meio.mp4
    ffmpeg -i "$ARQUIVO" -c copy -ss 00:00:10  -avoid_negative_ts 1  fim.mp4

    # Inserindo texto na parte do meio
    ffmpeg -i meio.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf':text='Liberado para $nome - $cpf':x=200:y=10:fontsize=16" -avoid_negative_ts 1   meio-texto.mp4

    # Montando lista para concatenar os arquivos
    echo -e "file 'inicio.mp4'\nfile 'meio-texto.mp4'\nfile 'fim.mp4'" > lista.txt

    # Concatenando os arquivos
    ffmpeg -f concat -i lista.txt -c copy  "/var/www/Arquivos/videos/$cpf/$ARQ_DESTINO"

    # Removendo arquivos temporários utilizados
    rm inicio.mp4 meio.mp4 fim.mp4 meio-texto.mp4 lista.txt

done
```

Comment: Murilo, seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Recomendo você explicar um pouco sua resposta, para que fique claro para o usuario que perguntou, o que estava errado ou o que modificou no codigo.